# Ansible to manage AKS cluster (namespace & list pods)

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, azure-aks

I have a aks cluster created in Azure through ansible playbook and now I would like to manage the aks cluster through playbooks for eg: create namespace and list pods. The module I'm using for namespace and list pods is azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aks and azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aks_info.

In the Ansible module documentation I don't see supporting parameters for creating a namespace. Is it possible to create namespace with Ansible playbooks.
[Ansible module link``](https://%20https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_aks_module.html)

I'm a beginner to Ansible and appreciate if anyone could help me get through this block.